# How to tell correctly if a circuit is pull-high type or pull-low type?

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, homework, pullup, pulldown

I have been giving this assignment working with Arduino that would light up a 7-segment component, when a push button is pressed.

Is there an intuitive way of looking at the circuit and recognize immediately whether it is pull-high type or pull-low type?

[image: Image: LED Blink with push button]

Edit:

I think the correct answer could be related to the position of the pushbutton, which state is determined by using the digitalRead(**D2**) function.
After switching the position of the latter with the resistor between the **Ground** pin and **D2** node, the circuit behaves from pull-low type as in the schematic to pull-high type. see [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkfBc.png)

Comment: Brad - Welcome :-) Please [edit] the question and add your own analysis. What do you think is the correct answer, and why? Also, from the perspective of *which component* are you asking about pull-up vs. pull-down? (P.S. Next time, please add a larger schematic. Although the necessary details are *just* visible on your schematic, larger ones are preferable. Also, please read the site [tour] and [help] to see the site rules and see how Stack Exchange sites are different from typical internet forums.) Thanks.

Comment: Adding to @SamGibson point: *larger schematics are preferable* but up to a point. Here, don't go larger than twice the size shown. Otherwise, people lose the question flow while scrolling past big pictures. Thanks and a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: What voltage is pin `D2` connected to when the button is *not* pressed? That is the normal state. It has to be pulled the other way when the button is pressed.

Comment: @TonyM Glad to know about it, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way yo tell is by looking at the datasheet of the microcontroller. However, if you're trying to determine this by experimenting because let's say you "lost the datasheet" then you can do it with an LED and a resistor.

You can start with assuming that that's an active high circuit and so hook your resistor and LED in series with resistor to the IO and LED to GND. If it doesn't turn on then it's an active low, if it does it's an active high.

All experiments start with an assumption.

Comment: What about push-pull output?

Comment: You mean like as in an amplifier push-pull? In digital everything is either active low or active high. There's no both, otherwise it defeats the purpose. Right?

Comment: No. Active high, active low. What does active or passive mean?